# Itextsharp - Automatic open print preview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, itext

Itextsharp auto open windows print priview like windows.print() in javascipt. how?
i want that after displaying the pdf in browser it will automatic print preview.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.print(); },5000);
```

Where the 5000 is the time in milliseconds you want to wait before the popup

Comment: Hi Mick. i tried your code but encounter error. i can already preview the pdf my browser but i want to open auto print dialog. like it already hit the ctrl + p